# postgres: must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "table1"

| h1 | h2 | street_number | street | municipality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 9 | 121 | Gompelbaan | Mol |
| 2 | 14 | 118 | Gompelbaan | Mol |
| 7 | 17 | 78 | Tortelstraat | Mol |
| 9 | 2 | 17 | Borgerlaan | Balen |
| 2 | 11 | 12 | Dorpsstraat | Turnhout |
| 4 | 29 | 172 | Gompelbaan | Mol |

Given an address (as example I take Gompelbaan 121, Mol), I want to find the 10 nearest neighbours that exist in the database and average the columns h1 and h2 of these addresses.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT h1, h2
FROM table1
WHERE municipality = 'Mol' and street = 'Gompelbaan'
ORDER BY @(SELECT substring(SPLIT_PART(street_number, '-', 1) from '^[0-9]+')::DECIMAL - 121)
limit 10
```

Which works great and gives me the individual h1 and h2 of the 10 nearest addresses.
However, when I want the average:

```
SELECT AVG(h1)
FROM table1
WHERE municipality = 'Mol' and street = 'Gompelbaan'
ORDER BY @(SELECT substring(SPLIT_PART(street_number, '-', 1) from '^[0-9]+')::DECIMAL - 121)
limit 10
```

I get the error:

> column "table1.street_number" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I also tried this with filter instead:

```
query = " SELECT AVG(h1) FILTER(WHERE municipality = 'Mol' and street = 'Gompelbaan') FROM table1 ORDER BY @(SELECT substring(SPLIT_PART(street_number, '-', 1) from '^[0-9]+') :: DECIMAL - 121) limit 10"
```

Which returns the error:

> subquery uses ungrouped column "table1.street_number" from outer query

How would I fix this issue?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to order something if it isn't in your select list right? That's step 1. Step is put the expression in your group by

Comment: I don't see any way in your table to determine geographical proximity between two addresses.  You might want to comment on this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There isn't, the nearest 10 addresses are defined as the nearest 10 street numbers in the same street as the given address. This is done in the order by statement with @(street_number - 121) limit 10, e.g. it will find the 10 nearest addresses in the database to the street number 121 on the same street

Answer (score 1):

I would take this approach and use your first query as a sub-query:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(H1) 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT h1, h2 FROM table1 WHERE municipality = 'Mol' and street = 'Gompelbaan' ORDER BY @(SELECT substring(SPLIT_PART(street_number_label, '-', 1) from '^[0-9]+') :: DECIMAL - 121) limit 10
    ) SUB1
```